# How to properly Dirty rectangles for simple application: Logic Issue

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently just testing the waters with Pygame display as I am extremely new to the module.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame 

pygame.init() 

SCALE = 1
display_width = int(1200 * SCALE)
display_height = int(800 * SCALE)
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (44, 215, 223)
red = (255, 67, 34)
blue = (77, 77, 77)

count = 0
running = True
box1_image = True
box3_image = True

background = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Justi/source/repos/03 Game/Game/assets/background.jpg')
dirty_spot = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Justi/source/repos/03 Game/Game/assets/dirty.png')

background_resized = pygame.transform.scale(dirty_spot, (display_width, display_height))
background_rect = background_resized.get_rect()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(background_rect.size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Game 1") 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

dirty_spot_resized = pygame.transform.scale(dirty_spot, (200, 200))
square_dirty_spot = dirty_spot_resized.convert()
rect_dirty_spot = square_dirty_spot.get_rect()

def dirtyspot1(imagex, imagey):

    gameDisplay.blit(dirty_spot_resized, (imagex,imagey))

while running:

    rects = []
    if rects != []:
        pygame.display.update(rects)        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                running = False

    #if box3_image: #Replacing the Bool passing variable with a simple loop count to trigger the else condition
    if count < 50:
        print("Test 1")
        dirtyspot1(0,0)
        pygame.display.update() 
    else:
        print("Test 2")
        dirty_rect = background.subsurface(rect_dirty_spot)
        gameDisplay.blit(dirty_rect, (0,0))
        rects.append(pygame.Rect(0,0, 200, 200))
        
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    clock.tick(30)
    count += 1

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

`box1_image`  & `box1_image`  are bool variables to flag certain condition which is passed from another function.

But I have gotten the passing of said variables working by doing a simple test with `print("Test 2")`. However, when it tries to blit `dirty_rect`. Nothing changes on the pygame display.

Assets (if needed):
[background.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2VPv.jpg)
[dirty.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx0yj.png)

May I check what is missing to properly "remove/delete" the `dirty_spot` blit? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pygame 
    
pygame.init() 

SCALE = 1
display_width = int(1200 * SCALE)
display_height = int(800 * SCALE)
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (44, 215, 223)
red = (255, 67, 34)
blue = (77, 77, 77)

count = 0
running = True
box1_image = True
box3_image = True

background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
dirty_spot = pygame.image.load('dirty.png')

background_resized = pygame.transform.scale(background, (display_width, display_height))
background_rect = background_resized.get_rect()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game 1") 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

dirty_spot_resized = pygame.transform.scale(dirty_spot, (200, 200))
square_dirty_spot = dirty_spot_resized.convert()
rect_dirty_spot = square_dirty_spot.get_rect()

show_dirt = False

def dirtyspot1(imagex, imagey):

    gameDisplay.blit(dirty_spot_resized, (imagex,imagey))

while running:

    rects = []
    if rects != []:
        pygame.display.update(rects)        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                running = False
            
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                show_dirt = not show_dirt
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                rect_dirty_spot.y -= 5
            
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                rect_dirty_spot.y += 5
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rect_dirty_spot.x += 5
            
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                rect_dirty_spot.x -= 5
                
    gameDisplay.blit(background_resized, (0,0))

    if show_dirt:
        gameDisplay.blit(dirty_spot_resized, rect_dirty_spot)
        
    pygame.display.update() 
        
    clock.tick(5)
    count += 1

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: @marienbad StackOverflow is not a dialog between a questioner and an answerer. It is question an answer database for all contributors. Each question and answer has an impact on all contributors. Wrong answers lead to confusions and have to be corrected or deleted. The comment section is not intended for the explanation of an answer. Comments can be deleted. The explanation has to be put in the answer.

Comment: Where did my other comment go? There was an earlier exchange and it has completely disappeared? I iz confuzed.

Answer (score 1):

like this? (I changed the FPS to 5 so it takes a while to change)

```
import pygame 

pygame.init() 

SCALE = 1
display_width = int(1200 * SCALE)
display_height = int(800 * SCALE)
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (44, 215, 223)
red = (255, 67, 34)
blue = (77, 77, 77)

count = 0
running = True
box1_image = True
box3_image = True

background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
dirty_spot = pygame.image.load('dirty.png')

background_resized = pygame.transform.scale(background, (display_width, display_height))
background_rect = background_resized.get_rect()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(background_rect.size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Game 1") 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

dirty_spot_resized = pygame.transform.scale(dirty_spot, (200, 200))
square_dirty_spot = dirty_spot_resized.convert()
rect_dirty_spot = square_dirty_spot.get_rect()

def dirtyspot1(imagex, imagey):

    gameDisplay.blit(dirty_spot_resized, (imagex,imagey))

while running:

    rects = []
    if rects != []:
        pygame.display.update(rects)        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                running = False

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    
    #if box3_image: #Replacing the Bool passing variable with a simple loop count to trigger the else condition
    if count < 50:
        print("Test 1")
        dirtyspot1(0,0)
    else:
        print("Test 2")
        dirty_rect = background.subsurface(rect_dirty_spot)
        gameDisplay.blit(dirty_rect, (0,0))
        rects.append(pygame.Rect(0,0, 200, 200))
   
    pygame.display.update() 
        
    clock.tick(5)
    count += 1

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I think you have misunderstood things.  You can blit one image or surface on top of another, and you build things up like that, then blit them to the display and finally update the display.

You have this line:

`background_resized = pygame.transform.scale(dirty_spot, (display_width, display_height))`

which I assume should be background not dirty_spot.

I moved the call to display.update() out of the if loop, because you call display.update() last.